# map initialization: object code is 50 times larger than source code

Tags: c++, dictionary, initialization, constants

I am working in C++ with BCC32. I initialized a map with about 1000 entries like this:

```
extern map<string, string> city ;
void region_init_0 (void) { 
city["abc01"] = "Brussels" ;
city["xyz03"] = "Liege" ;
...
}
```

The length of the .cpp file is 40 KB. After compilation, I get a .obj file of 2.2 MB. After linking with other modules, the .exe file is also 2 MB longer than before I added the map. I don't understand why I get this ratio of 50 between the length of the object code and the total length of the ASCII strings.

How can I reduce that? I guess that there must be more clever ways to initialize a map that will remain constant during the execution of the program.

Thanks.

Comment: Compiler optimizations should reduce the binary file size, if you aren't already using it.

Comment: The 2.2MB .obj file is compiled by that cpp file you listed?

Comment: Try without debug symbols as well, or strip the executable.

Comment: Have you though about loading the data from a file run-time instead?

Comment: @flipchart Compiler optimizations will frequently increase the size of the object file.  Turning off or striping debugging information will significantly reduce it, at the cost of not being able to use the debugger on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an external function and pass the raw cstrings to it:

```
extern std::map<std::string, std::string> city;

/* somehow make sure it cannot be inlined */
extern void AddCity(const char* const a, const char* const b) __attribute__((__noinline__));

void region_init_0 (void) {
    AddCity("abc01","Brussels");
    AddCity("xyz03","Liege");
    ...
}

extern void AddCity(const char* const a, const char* const b) {
    city[a] = b;
}
```

I simulated your case on my system, and it brought the executable size down to 100K (stripped) from 924K. One difference in the simulation is that you'll export more strings, so the ratio will not be equal.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed this example and the .obj file is just slightly larger than the .cpp file and the generated .exe is okay too. Excellent!

Answer (score 3):

Have you enabled **optimizations** in your compiler?

You could perhaps have some code like

```
typedef std::pair<const char*,const char*> paircstr_t;
const paircstr_t initarr[] = {
  { "abc01", "Brussels" },
  { "xyz02", "Paris" },
  /// etc...
  { (const char*)0, (const char*)0 } // terminating null placeholder
};

extern map<string, string> city ;
void region_init_0 (void) { 
   for (int i = 0;; i++) {
      const char* curname = initarr[i].first;
      const char* curcity = initarr[i].second;
      if (!curname || !curcity) break;
      map[curname] = curcity;
   }
}
```

The object code size might be smaller, but the runtime heap size won't change.

Comment: +1. I think it could be worthwhile to replace the pair with an array of size 2. The compiler might forget to optimize away the pair constructor.

Comment: On GCC the pair is a structure of two elements.

Comment: Ah. So no constructor... right. Then there should be no difference.

Comment: Actually, that crashes GCC 4.6.2, so I reported http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51092

Comment: So indeed, declaring `strcut paircstr_t { const char*name; const char*city; }` could be better.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess: Is operator[] inline? Hopefully you can change this by (un)defining some preprocessor constant. Is the release build larger or smaller than debug?

Answer (score 1):

You've added a lot of code.  In the object file, there are not just the
strings, but the generated code, and probably debugging information
(e.g. line number information) for every line.  It all adds up.

This is also a very poor way to do initialize a map; unless it is
machine generated code, you don't want to write it.  (And while perhaps
not an issue here, it means that the map can't be `const`.)  A more
typical solution to initialize a map might be something like:

```
struct MapInitializer
{
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> MapType

    char const* key;
    char const* value;
    operator MapType::value_type() const
    {
        return MapType::value_type(key, value);
    }
};

static MapInitializer initialValues[] =
{
    { "abc01", "Brussels" },
    { "xyz03", "Liege"    },
    //  ...
};
```

and then:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> city(
        std::begin( initialValues ), std::end( initialValues ) );
```

(If the initialization must be deferred to a later function call, then:

```
city = std::map<std::string, std::string>(
        std::begin( initialValues ), std::end( initialValues ) );
```

can be used.  But generally, if the map is to be initialized with a
compile time constant list, it's best to do it in the definition of the
variable, as above.)